# How to use polymorph function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

There is a function that adds data to localstorage:

```
add(type: "point" | "object", body: FavouritesBodyPoint | FavouritesBodyObject) {
    // TODO
}

export interface FavouritesBodyPoint {}
export interface FavouritesBodyObject {}
```

Problem is that I want to extend the available `type` and `body` for adding. Should I create a new function or can use union type?

How to make this polymorph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)

```js
export interface FavouritesBodyPoint {
  tag: 'FavouritesBodyPoint'
}
export interface FavouritesBodyObject {
  tag: 'FavouritesBodyObject'
}

function add(type: "object", body: FavouritesBodyObject): void
function add(type: "point", body: FavouritesBodyPoint): void
function add(type: "point" | "object", body: FavouritesBodyPoint | FavouritesBodyObject) {
  // TODO
}

add('point', {
  tag: 'FavouritesBodyPoint'
}) // ok

add('object', {
  tag: 'FavouritesBodyPoint'
}) // expected error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgMUwDcIBXKBVAZwCEIATATwAUJl4BvAKDjhkwDmALjgByQiXKVgtBizYpRXAL5dQkWIhRosuAsTIVqdJgHkARgCtg2Tjz6CR4g1ONyL120tVd0pJLYIEEhwmPT0ABQwjGDAIgBEEFY2MPEANHDmciIShtKyZsm2AJQiJAj0vv6BwaHhUTFxcPGQ7OmZ2fqSRjIm8uylcOWVfgEwQSFhkdGxCa0o8XAAPs1JnqkZWUw5Lj0F-SjLXXluhevFcNy8APTXcAAqpgAipipcXFMRovMwohlXDmEYlyrl6clY7G8F1ucAgAGt3p9RGsUn9LvZ%20EDnN18n0IYoVNC7uoUsB6HA0FBoEA)

Because TS is about structural typing, both `FavouritesBodyPoint, FavouritesBodyObject` are equal from TS perspective, thats why I have added extra `tag` property